# How to store and retrieve an excel file in oracle apex 19.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to store an excel file in a column and want it back with the same file (excel). I created a column with blob datatype to store the file and set the column type as download blob in classic report in order to download that file back in same extension, but I am encountering an error in report section as it is demonstrated in below screenshot.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: To me, it looks more like an interactive (than classic) report. Apart from that, how is anyone supposed to know what you did? Obviously, something wrong - otherwise Apex wouldn't raise an error. What was it, I have no idea as I have difficulties in debugging code I can't see. Consider creating an example on apex.oracle.com, provide login credentials so that someone could have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something similar to you, and these links helped me out. Maybe these may help you out, as well, until you are able to provide more input above.

- [File upload improvements](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2016/08/file-upload-improvements-in-apex-5-1/)
- [File download tips](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex-tips-file-download-from-a-button-or-link)
- [How to Link to or Download a File in Blob...](https://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2014/03/yet-another-post-how-to-link-to.html)